# Converting code within a Jupyter Notebook w/ no access to command line

Tags: ipad, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I’m on an iPad (Juno) pure python environment and I’m trying to convert beautifulsoup4 from python2 to python3 with 2to3. With NO access to the command line how can I achieve this through jupyter cells?

How to I load and call 2to3 and then apply that to the bs4 package directory?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to follow the instructions involving 2to3 from the [Beautiful Soup website](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/#Download), since bs4 is available via PyPI. You should be able to install it using [Juno's package installer](https://juno.sh/juno-pypi-package-installer/):

> There are two ways to install additional pure Python packages in Juno:
>
> - Manually put package sources into /site-packages directory in Juno’s on-device storage.
> - Install using Juno’s PyPI package installer (tap notebook title -> Install Python Package).
>
> [...]
>
> Juno’s package installer is supposed to make installation process a bit easier. Simply provide package name in the search bar (the name you would otherwise use with pip command), and Juno will fetch package details from PyPI and, if it has supported distributions, will attempt to install it to your iPad or iPhone.

If that doesn't work, you could try downloading the package from [it's PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/#files) and putting the `bs4` folder from the py3-wheel (which is just a .zip in disguise) into the `site-packages` folder. On my regular computer, I was able to import that folder from Python 3.